# Pip installing to one folder but jupyter pulls packages from another folder

Tags: python, pip, jupyter

To preface I am using a Mac with the Anaconda distribution! (New-ish to mac so please bear with me)

### My problem

I am using pip install to install packages (simpy, plotly etc). However the packages won't import correctly, it looks like my Anaconda distribution is pulling from another folder. How do I repoint my anaconda distribution to use the right folder so when I pip install, I don't have to keep switching environments?

[image: Text]

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and enter `conda install simpy`

Comment: Yea I ended up following this article, turns out the graphical installation of anaconda is not the way to go and the CLI version is much better. Thank you! 

https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-successfully-install-anaconda-on-a-mac-and-actually-get-it-to-work-53ce18025f97